# is there a way I can fix my useSelector hook that is showing undefined?

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, useselector

I am learning to build a add to cart functionality using redux-toolkit. I clone this project online so I can follow step by step. I ran into trouble when I want to use the selector to select my state it says not defined.

Here is my codesandbox code please help. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wind-n8mi3v?file=/src/centralStore.js/store.js
I need to say one more time that my main issue is
state not been defined when I use the selector hook. It renders my forEach useless.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js, you should modify to this

```
const cart = useSelector(( state)=> state.reducer.cart)
```

(Originally, your code was

```
const cart = useSelector(( state)=> state.cart)
```

because in your store.js, you use one more layer of "reducer"